# GET request not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to record a link click through jquery to execute a php file but nothing is hapening.

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $.get("record.php", { id: "a" }, function(data){});
});
```

Link

```
<a id='click' href='http://some link' target='_blank'>Start Download</a>
```

Record

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO clicks VALUES ('','','','','')");
}
```

Running the php fron the file itself works good but from the jquery it doesnt

Any help please?

Comment: what exactly does not work..? do you get any errors..in console ..?

Comment: What response is returned from the server? Take a look in your browser's debugging tools (try echoing out any `mysql_error()` or even a success message).

Comment: Could you specify "nothing is happening" ? Does your php file get hit? Do you get any javascript errors? Any Http errors in fiddler / net tab? Are any of your callbacks hit in jQuery?

Comment: A tool like Firebug can be handy here as well.

Comment: There is no errors, when i click the link literally nothing happends and the record is not inserted. if i go to the php file itself and add an id it inserts so it isnt the PHP that is making it not work.

Comment: How do you know nothing is happening? You're not doing anything with the data that is being returned.

Comment: Im not returning anything, im using it to insert a query from the php file

Comment: Once again, check the ajax call with firebug(firefox) or the chrome console!

Comment: Where's that script located? If it's not right before the `</body>` tag (the very end of the document, basically) you'll need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` call.

Comment: Post the entire HTML, perhaps you have some mistakes in the HTML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#click').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("record.php", { id: "a" }, function(data){});
});
```

Comment: There is no difference because he is opening the URL in a new window, so the ajax call won't be interrupted anyway.

Comment: That just make the link not go to the specified url and still does not record the click.

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor tag you do not have to specify `href`

```
<a id='click' href='#'>Start Download</a>

$('#click').click(function(){
    $.get("record.php", { "id": "a" }, function(data){
       // Place here some logic (if you wish to do after getting your data from record.php

       window.location.href = 'your_url.php';
    });
});
```

Comment: But i need the href to go to a link after it records the click

Comment: so do it at the `callback` (Updated the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Change your 
`<a id='click' href='http://some link' target='_blank'>Start Download</a>` 
to:
`<a id='click' href='javascript:void(0);'>Start Download</a>`

Changed the href

In jQuery :

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $.get("record.php", { id: "a" }, function(data){
        //some code here
    }).done(function() { window.location.href ='http://some link'; });
});
```

Comment: But i need the href to go somewhere?

Comment: Make it after $get, use window.location in javascript.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra that doesn't fail gracefully if Javascript is disabled.

Comment: @BartFriederichs : Yup it will, even the $.get will not work in that case, Majority of the websites wont work properly if js is disabled :)

Comment: Even so, it doesn't open it in a new window - maybe that is a requirement.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra perhaps they don't, but they should. They might not have all functionality, but something as simple as a link should fail gracefully and keep working.

Comment: I have it working without the link in the href but a non javascript way of sending them to the page would be better

Comment: @BrendanMullan : "non javascript way of sending them to the page would be better" you will not be able to call click event and $.get

Comment: I just noticed the problem is with pretty urls, if i try it with the raw php url it will work but with the pretty url it wont, hmm

Comment: Maybe removing the href isn't a good idea. What is an anchor for without its target url?
You could add preventDefault() to the click event, and then retrieve the href from the event [target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp), redirecting the user to it afterwards. Doing so, you won't lose the link reference if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: @Seza could you give me an example

Comment: <a href="http://mypage.com">some link</a>

<script>
$('a').click(function(e){
$.get("record.php", { id: "a" }, function(data){
        //some code here
    }).done(function() { window.location.href =e.target.href; });
});
</script>

Comment: That works from the raw .php but using the pretty url /download it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass your data as a json object and use a callback, try

```
$.get("test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {
       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

From : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Functionally equivalent (i.e. it's just a different syntax to achieve the exact same thing) as the code he already has.